# While importing product report show error on image column, error is "General system exception happened". How to resolve It?

Tags: magento2

While importing product to magento2 its give error and in report file it point out the image column. How to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this please try to turn off the below option. It will let you import the CSV.

Go to Store => Configuraiton => Sales => Google Api and set to NO for Enable Content Experiments